# What are good and bad question types for RPG Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

This is a Community Wiki entry designed to enumerate a list of common question types, whether they should be asked here, and what things an asker or answerer should be advised of.

Please add common question types and vote them up/down based on whether you think they are good question types for the site.  Add comments to the question if you would like to add guidance, like "but you need to do X" or "only in the case of Y," or "this should be a Community Wiki."

If extensive discussion on one is required (and I assume often it will be), let's do it in a separate meta thread, and then add/vote it here for brevity.

Comment: +1 for doing this. With a site like this, we need to be able to define scope.

Comment: Doing this was the [first stage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208?phase=definition) of creating this site.

Answer (score 6):

What is the definition of "X", where X is a general roleplaying term like railroading, immersion, indie game, munchkin, sandbox, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

Why should I play/sell me on/tell me about Game X - basically asking for information about a specific game, to convince me I want to play it.

Comment: I'd approve of this type, if the question is phrased in the manner "What are the accepted positive aspects of role-playing game X"?

Answer (score 5):

In [a specific game system] I'm having difficulty determining what should happen under [circumstances]. What's the fair/appropriate interpretation of the rules?

Answer (score 4):

What game/system is good for situation "X", where X is a class of people like newbies, or kids, or wargamers, or women; a genre like "pulp" or "fantasy" or "western" or "pirates"; or similar?

Comment: As long as we get real, well thought answers. I'm always frustrated when I can't figure out why the game was recommended.

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition of "X", where X is a commonly defined term available on Wikipedia or TV Tropes like "macguffin" or "jump the shark"?

Comment: Agreed. A better question would be "How do I do X in a game of Y". The Shadowrun Noir question is a great example of that.

Answer (score -1):

'Help me find a playgroup'.

Comment: Why not "how do I find a playgroup in 'City X' ?"